# Using Azure App Service Mobile App or Azure Mobile Services Offline Sync SQLite (Xamarin, Ionic, PhoneGap)

Tags: cordova, azure, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, azure-mobile-services

Hy

I'm evaluating a Cross-Platform Mobile Framework at the moment, actually I'm comparing Xamarin versus Ionic (PhoneGap).

I've a question regarding using Azure App Service Mobile App (Preview) or Azure Mobile Services with this two frameworks.

Xamarin:

- I know it is possible to use an Azure App Service Mobile App as a Backend and to use the "Offline data sync" SDK feature of Azure Mobile Apps to use my SQLite Database (within my Xamarin Application) offline and sync it later, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync-preview/

Ionic (PhoneGap):

- Is the above scenario also possible with Ionic (with Azure App Service Mobile App (Preview) or Azure Mobile Services)?

Thanks for your help,

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Update 6/13/16) Offline data sync support for Cordova is in progress and will be released as a preview within the next few months. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client.